# Using an Android AVD for system app/services development

Tags: android

Long time ago (say ~2014s), I used to build and debug android AOSP components directly on AVD - Camera.apk, cameraHAL.so, mediaService, etc...
I used to build them directly from the main branch of AOSP, using a "lunch goldfish..." config and make.

Nowadays (Android 9/10) this doesn't seem possible anymore. AVDs are a "Production build", which doesn't allow adb root;adb remount properly. This means, that pushing the newly built binaries to the device impossible.
Also there is no exact matching between the AVD version from Android Studio to the AOSP source code/manifest.

My questions are:
1. Is it still possible to use AVD for development and build binaries from AOSP to push to AVD?
2. If this is not possible, what are the best possible solutions. E.g. can I use at least some rooted pixel phone to achieve my goal - simply build binary from any part of the Android source tree and push it to device (through adb)?

Thank you in advance.